# Passing values from Broadcast receiver to Instrumentation class in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, instrumentation

In my project am using broadcast reveiver for reading incomming messages. At the same time I have an Instrumentation class. In this class have an function like

```
publi void testMethod(){
   String strMessage = "";
   solo.enterText(solo.getEditText(0),strMessage);
 }
```

I need to read the incomming message and pass the message content to this instrumentation class. I tried by using static variable.

```
  public class Globals{
     public String static strMessage = "";
  }
```

Am reading the incomming message and update the static varibale "strMessage" and am refering in the Instrumnetation class. But am not getting updated value of strMessage inside the testMethod(). Is there any other way to do this.
Any one help me on this??

Answer (score 0):

pass the message through Bundle if the class is extending activity or else store the msg in shared preference and access it in the class like this

```
SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getSharedPreferences("Message", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor MessageEditor = settingsActivity.edit();
                outBoxEditor.putString ("RBSelected",Msg);
// here msg is what u get 
                outBoxEditor.commit();
```

and in the Instrumentation class

```
SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getSharedPreferences("Message", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
String message = settingActivity.getString("Message","");
```

Comment: :: The SharedPreferences class is used to store and retrieve the persistent <key,value> pair for a activity. But not for across the activities.

Comment: if required to store single value we can use it across multiple activities also.